# Automate Excel datas to a Word Document with Python

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, python-docx

Here's my problem : I have 1000 names and addresses on an Excel Sheet and I have to write a letter on Word for every single names .

Example of the letter below (red sign).

I would like to automate the process by using python. Could you give me your ideas about it ? How would you start and what packages would you use ?

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use Python? Why not just use Word's built in [Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Word-mail-merge-A-walk-through-the-process-4ad61088-e108-4f56-b60d-e3c7d30c954a)?  That's going to be way simpler, more straightforward, and you're good to go right now if you already have the addresses in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options of course, but something that would work is to use the `openpyxl` package to open and read the Excel file and then use `python-docx` to write the letter file.